# Rails_admin gemfile, bundle install, rails version question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While trying to install Rails admin, I added it to my gem file as instructed. I deleted the gemfile.lock

Then I ran bundle install. I got this message:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails_admin depends on
      rails (~> 3.0.3)

    rails (3.0.1)
```

I am using rails 3.0.1, not really sure I understand the issue? But its obviously stopping me from installing.

Also, if I put rails_admin in the gem file like so:

gem 'rails_admin'

instead of:

gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'

that seems to install it a version 0.0.0 and then doesn't proceed to do anything (so clearly thats not right either).

Is there a version I can specify that might work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the gem now required rails 3.0.3 and you are using 3.0.1

~> means at least this tiny revision or greater.
E.G. ~> 3.0.3 means 3.0.x where x >= 3

As for what gem version will work on 3.0.1 I do not know.